# include_once not working but when i delete some methods work?

Tags: php

Hi guys what would be the reasons of a non working include_once?
i think something wrong in my methods because i used (class with methods and interface implemented )
Please tell me if you want more information.
i need solution beacause i'm preparing a project :/

this is my page config.php

```
<?php 

include_once '../connexion/Connexion.php';
include_once '../Services/UtilisateurService.php'; 
 include_once '../Services/AssocService.php';
session_start();

$nom = '';
$motpass = '';
    $profile='';
    $observation='';
$id = 0;
$update = false;

if (isset($_POST['save'])) 
    {

            $nom = $_POST['nom'];
    $motpass = $_POST['password'];
            $profile = $_POST['profil'];
            $observation = $_POST['observation'];
            $dot=new UtilisateurService();
            $ope=new Utilisateur(NULL,$nom,$password,$profil,$observation);
            $dot->create($ope);

            $_SESSION['message'] = "Utilisateur Enregistre"; 
    header('location: ../Goperateur.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['update'])) 
{ 
            $es = new AssocService(); 
            $es->update($es->finById($id));
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Utilisateur Modifier!";
        header('location: ./Goperateur.php');

}

  if(isset($_POST['ajouter']))
    {   
        $nom=$_POST['nom'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $profil=$_POST['profil'];
        $observation=$_POST['observation'];
        $dot=new UtilisateurService();
        $ope=new Utilisateur($idd,$nom,$password,$profil,$observation);
        $dot->create($ope);
        header("location:./Goperateur.php");

    }

if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
{       
    $id = $_GET['id'];
        $es = new AssocService();
        $es->delete($es->findById($id));

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Utilisateur suprimer"; 
    header('location: ../Goperateur.php');
}
```

and this is my page index

```
<?php include_once './action/configOperateur.php';?>
   <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = true;
        $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM  utilisateur WHERE id_utilisateur=$id");

        if (count($record) == 1 ) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $nom = $n['nom'];
            $motpass = $n['mot_passe'];
                        $profile=$n['profil'];
                        $observation=$n['observation'];
        }
    }
?>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-cls-top " role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
            </div>
  <div style="color: white;
padding: 15px 50px 5px 50px;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;">

<script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger square-btn-adjust">Se déconnecter </a> </div>
        </nav>   
           <!-- /. NAV TOP  -->
                <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                <li class="text-center">
                                    <img src="assets/img/radeema.png" class=""/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i>Tableau de bord</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                         <a  href="Operateur.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i> Gestion des Operateurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="dotation/DotationForm.php"><i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:36px"></i> Gestion de Dotation</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a   href=""><i style="font-size:36px" class="fa">&#xf114;</i> Gestion des Puces</a>
                    </li>   
                      <li  >
                        <a  href=""><i class="fa fa-table fa-3x"></i> Gestion Des Entites</a>
                    </li>
                    <li  >
                        <a  href=""><i class="fa fa-male" style="font-size:36px"></i> Gestion de Personnels </a>
                    </li>
                    <li  >
                        <a  href="AssPersPuce.php"><i class="fa fa-male" style="font-size:36px"></i> Association Personnels-Puces </a>
                    </li>
        </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>  
        <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" >
            <div id="page-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Gestion des operateurs </h2> 
                        <h5> </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>              
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
                  <hr />
                   <?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
                  <div style="margin: 30px auto; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    color: #3c763d; 
    background: #dff0d8; 
    border: 1px solid #3c763d;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;">
        <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['message']; 
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!-- Form Elements -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <form method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Nom</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" placeholder="entre le nom Complet" value="<?php echo $nom; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Mot de Pass</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="entre mot de pass" value="<?php echo $motpass; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Selectioner le profil</label>
                                                    <select name="profil" class="form-control">
                                                        <?php if($profile=='operateur') 
                                                        {?>
                                                        <option value="admin">Operateur</option>
                                                        <option value="operateur">Admin</option>
                                                        <?php } 
                                                        else 
                                                        {
                                                            ?>
                                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                                        <option value="operateur">Operateur</option>
                                                        <?php }?>
                                                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Observation</label>
                                                    <textarea type="text" name="observation" class="form-control" rows="3" ><?php echo $observation; ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                                <?php if ($update == false): ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="ajouter" >Ajouter</button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn " type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >Modifier</button>
<?php endif ?>
                                                <button name="annuler" type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Annuler</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    <hr/>
        <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             Liste des Operateur
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Nom</th>
                                            <th>Motsepass</th>
                                            <th>Profil</th>
                                            <th>Observation</th>
                                            <th>Modifier</th>
                                            <th>Suprimer</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="odd gradeX">

                                        <?php
                                            require_once './Services/UtilisateurService.php';
                                            require_once './Classes/Utilisateur.php';
                                            $dot=new UtilisateurService();
                                            foreach ($dot->findAll() as $key=>$e) 
                                            {
                                        ?>
                                            <form method="post" action="Operateur.php">   
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="center"><?php echo $e->getNom();?></td>
                                                <td class="center"><?php echo $e->getMotdepasse();?></td>
                                                <td class="center"><?php echo $e->getProfil();?></td>
                                                <td class="center"><?php echo $e->getObservation();?></td>

                                                <td><a href="<?php echo "Goperateur.php?&edit=".$e->getId_ut().""?>">Modifier</a></td>
                                                <td><a href="<?php echo "./action/configOperateur.php?&id=".$e->getId_ut()."" ?>">Suprimer</a></td>
                                            </tr>

                                        <?php

                                        }

                                        ?>
                                         </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: What errors are u getting ?

Comment: Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../Services/AssocService.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestDotation\action\configOperateur.php on line 5

Comment: Warning: include_once(../connexion/Connexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestDotation\action\configOperateur.php on line 3

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../connexion/Connexion.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestDotation\action\configOperateur.php on line 3

Warning: include_once(../Services/UtilisateurService.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestDotation\action\configOperateur.php on line 4

Comment: First the `session_start` should be the very first statement in your code. from the errors seems like you are having wrong paths make sure that the files are in the exact location ??

Comment: I'm sure they are in the exact location i have tried a lot of expressions include_once but still have the same errors